# Green and red chillies on same plant

Tags: peppers

We moved to our house in the late summer and found a plant in the garden full of long green chilis.  It produced well into the autumn and all chillies were green.  Then, in the spring, it started to bud and produce all red chillies - with one or two half red and half green.  Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Red chilies are ripe, greens are not.

Comment: And the ripening process is sometimes very non-uniform.